# Raspberry Pi > CRTMPServer > JWplayer

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a raspberry pi to stream to a crtmpserver, and from there to a webpage with JWplayer.

I am able to send video successfully to crtmpserver with this:

raspivid -t 0 -w 960 -h 540 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1000k -f rtsp -metadata title=teststream rtsp://192.168.1.20:5544/flvplayback

But am having trouble viewing the stream from crtmpserver using this is my html jwplayer code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement-teststream").setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources:[{
                file: 'rmtp://192.168.1.20:1935/live/teststream"
            }]
        }],
        height: 1080,
        primary: 'flash',
        width: 1920
    });
    </script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jwplayer 6.11 video not Play on ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620483/using-jwplayer-6-11-video-not-play-on-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
file: 'rmtp://192.168.1.20:1935/live/teststream"
```

to

```
file: 'rtmp://192.168.1.20:1935/live/teststream'
```

Note the rtmp not rmtp and double/single quotes